# UK certificate of eligibility

Tags: visas, uk-citizens, work, permits

I applied for a certificate of eligibility in the UK. I didn't have a bank statement account because I work in another country and I only send money back home. So the agency told me to trust any of my relatives or close friends and send him/her money so that he can send 980 GPB in the UK where I'll be working via any moneygram. When I get to the UK, withdraw the money myself.

So I was wondering, is there anything like that or it'a just a scam?

Comment: It looks like a scam, just because you probably don't need to involve moneygram. A certificate of eligibility for what? What objective are you trying to achieve?

Comment: If you don't have a bank account, you're probably going to struggle to get a legitimate UK visa, and anybody who tells you otherwise is trying to scam you.

Answer (score 25):

It’s going to be a certificate of regret for quite some time. There is no such thing. Run!

You obviously told them you don’t have any close friends or relatives in the UK so very shortly they are going to say ok in that case we can do you that favour. And You then kiss goodbye to your money

Just for the sake of completeness you do not need to pay any third party for a work permit. You need to pay UKVI when you apply for one.

Answer (score 12):

There is no such thing.  I crafted [this Google search](https://www.google.com/search?client=safari&hl=en&biw=1024&bih=649&ei=J8dHWtqILIKHjwTOmbfIDg&q=%22certificate%20of%20eligibility%22%20uk%20visa&oq=%22certificate%20of%20eligibility%22%20uk%20visa) (note the quotation marks).

The only hit is *this question*.

More broadly, the term "certificate of eligibility" is used for foreigners seeking to be students in Japan; British attorneys seeking certification to practice law; and US veterans seeking to use the VA home loan program.

The main point of Brexit is that UK is *not* desperately searching for foreigners to work in the UK and send their wages overseas.

However lots of dirtbags make money selling this belief to their own countrymen.  They sell dubious "services" that are either outright scams, or are *rather unlikely* to fool the vigilant British.

It is illegal to go to the UK to seek work, unless you enter on a type of visa that is specifically for working.  Those are hard to get.  As such, people often misuse non-working visas, get caught, and get banned from the UK and other anglo countries with which the UK interchages data.

Comment: suggested edit: change "dirtbags" to "scumbags"

Comment: Last time I did that, Captain America said "[LANGUAGE](https://youtu.be/jwIOIEunIJI?t=1s)" [...](https://youtu.be/jwIOIEunIJI?t=1s)

Comment: @Vickel I suppose "scambags" would be more appropriate.

Comment: It is illegal to go to the UK to seek work _unless you are a citizen of an EU or EEA country_ (which might change in March 2019).